# Issue with VF Pdf

Tags: apex, visualforce, css

I was able to display tabular report in vf pdf format.this report contains large no of pages. using  for displaying table body, but table header is coming in first page. i need to display header in each break up page. Tried with page  page-break-before:always css, but not working. Is there any way to identify page breakup and append the header at the starting of page break in pdf?

Answer (score 3):

A colleague of mine showed me this solution which I know works.

```
    <table width="100%" class="mainTable" style="-fs-table-paginate: paginate;">

        <thead style="display: table-header-group;">
            <tr>
                <th width="80px">TRANS DATE</th>
                <th width="120px">TRANS NO</th>
                <th width="120px">DOC REF</th>
                <th width="85px">TRANS TYPE</th>
                <th>PRODUCT/SERVICE DESCRIPTION</th>
                <th width="45px">CURR</th>
                <th width="120px">ORIGINAL AMOUNT</th>
                <th width="90px">AMOUNT DUE</th>
                <th width="70px">DUE DATE</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody style="display: table-row-group;">
            <!-- some rows -->
        </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Where are you putting the page-break-before:always tag?  You could try moving it to see if that helps.  Also, are you using div id="header" for the header on each page or something else?

Comment: Here's a link that you can use to help debug your PDF: http://eclecticgeek.com/dompdf/debug.php

Answer (score -1):

Does adding these style help?

```
    table { page-break-inside:auto }
    tr    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
    thead { display:table-header-group }
```